# magento import product tags via spreadsheet

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way of importing product tags via a spreadsheet?

if not through a module, can this be done through a script?

Answer (score 0):

Tags to be imported format should be like this

[image: TagSpreadsheet]

And place the about spreadsheet in `root/tagimport/tagsheet.csv`

and paste the following code in `root/tagimport/importtag.php`

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$fileName = 'importtag.csv';

getAttributeCsv($fileName);

function getAttributeCsv($fileName){
    $file = fopen($fileName,"r");
    $RemoveLine = 0;
    while(!feof($file)){
        $data = fgetcsv($file);
        if($RemoveLine != 0){
            $labelText[] = $data[1];
        }$RemoveLine++;
    }createAttribute($labelText);
    fclose($file);
}

function createAttribute($labelText)
{
    foreach($labelText as $tag){
        if($tag){
            $quote = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
            $quote->loadByName($tag);
            if(!$quote->getId()){
                $quote->setName($tag);
                $quote->setStatus(1);
                $quote->setFirstStoreId(0);
                $quote->setPopularity(0);
                $quote->save();

                ##### Save product tags in "tag_properties"
                $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
                $table = 'tag_properties';
                $query = "insert into ".$table." "."(tag_id,store_id,base_popularity) values "."(:tag_id, :store_id, :base_popularity)";

                $binds = array(
                    'tag_id'    => $quote->getTagId(),
                    'store_id'   => '1',
                    'base_popularity' => '0',   
                    );  
                $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
                echo 'Tags Imported Successfully';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

run the above php file using

```
www.yourdomain.com/tagimport/importtag.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tags csv like below, (the first col is product SKU, the second column is the tag name)

```
8697550050245,White Egg
6291104283077,Organic Egg
6291100152520,Eco Veg Fed Egg
5701607588896,Organic Egg
```

Below script will import the tags for you

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    ini_set('request_terminate_timeout', 0);
    set_time_limit(0);

    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app("admin");

    $storeId = 1;
    try {

        $h = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/var/tags.csv', 'r');

        if ($h !== FALSE) {

            $updated = '';
            $notFound = '';
            while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $sku = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $data[0]);
                $tagName = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\&\/\(\)\- ]/", '', $data[1]);

                $product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

                if(!empty($product) && !empty($tagName)) {

                    $tagName = strtolower($tagName);
                    $tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
                    $tag->loadByName($tagName);
                    if (!$tag->getId()) {
                        $tag->setName($tagName)
                            ->setFirstCustomerId(null)
                            ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
                            ->setStatus($tag->getApprovedStatus())
                            ->save();
                    }

                    $tag->saveRelation($product->getId(), null, $storeId);

                    $updated.= $sku.','.$tagName.'<br >';
                }else{
                    $notFound.= $sku.','.$tagName.'<br >';
                }
            }


            fclose($h);
        }

        echo $updated;
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "**************** BELOW TAGS ARE NOT UPDATED ********************************";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo $notFound;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
```